# Error when using orm with useService in Odoo 17

Tags: javascript, orm, odoo

I am working on a Todo List app using Owl in Odoo 17. Everything was going well until I tried to dynamically fetch and display data using orm with useService. I encountered the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'orm' in undefined
```

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. clone [this repo](https://github.com/amir-rismani/odoo-owl-app) somewhere
2. start odoo with this repo in the addons-path, on a recent version (`odoo 17`)
3. install the `odoo_owl_app` addon
4. go to the `/owl-app` route to see the result.

**Code:**
The `root.js` file contains the following codes:

```js
/** @odoo-module */

import { Component, useState, useSubEnv, onWillStart } from "@odoo/owl";
import { useService } from "@web/core/utils/hooks";


import { WebsiteLayout } from "./layouts/website/layout"
import { TodoForm } from "./components/todo_form/todo_form";
import { Todos } from "./components/todos/todos";

export class Root extends Component {
    static template = "odoo_owl_app.root";
    static components = { WebsiteLayout, TodoForm, Todos };
    static props = {};

    setup() {
        this.todos = useState([]);
        this.orm = useService("orm");
        this.model = 'odoo_owl_app.todo';

        this.handleChangeState = (event) => {
            const id = event.target.value;
            const index = this.todos.findIndex(todo => todo.id === parseInt(id))
            this.todos[index].is_completed = !this.todos[index].is_completed
        };

        this.handleEdit = (id, title) => {
            const index = this.todos.findIndex(todo => todo.id === parseInt(id))
            this.todos[index].title = title
        };

        this.handleRemove = (id) => {
            console.log('remove', id)
            const index = this.todos.findIndex(todo => todo.id === parseInt(id))
            this.todos.splice(index, 1);
        };

        this.onAdd = (title) => {
            const todo = {
                userId: 1,
                id: new Date().getTime(),
                title,
                is_completed: false
            }
            this.todos.push(todo)
        };
    }
}
```

When this code `this.orm = useService("orm");` is added to the setup, the following error is issued:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'orm' in undefined
```

**Additional Information:**

- Odoo Version: 17

**Projects:**

- [this repo](https://github.com/amir-rismani/odoo-owl-app)

I appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue and gaining a better understanding of using Owl with Odoo.

I have consulted the Owl and Odoo documentation, as well as searched online for solutions, but haven't been able to resolve the issue. The code follows the documentation, and I expected the dynamic data retrieval to work without errors.

Comment: You should move `scss` directory to the parent directory `static`, except for some CSS errors your app is working well

Answer (score 0):

Error mainly due to the mounting issues so please ensure that you have used `mountComponent` instead of `mount` in your javascript file file.

```
/** @odoo-module */
import { whenReady } from "@odoo/owl";
import { mountComponent } from "@web/env";
import { Root } from "./root";

whenReady(() => mountComponent(Root, document.body));
```